# soft deleted in laravel 5 apply physicaldelete not set deleted_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

my model is:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Province extends Model {

 // use SoftDeletes;

public $timestamps = false;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function country(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Country');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\User');
}

public function customers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Customer');
}

}
```

controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $province = Province::with('country')->where('id', $id)->first();

   // dd($province);
    $province->delete();
 }
```

when call  http://localhost:8080/pal/public/province/22/delete.

record 22 deleted physically from database.

what's missing?

Comment: Well you have commented out `use SoftDeletes`

Comment: because when uncommented in i got this error: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Comment: Yes probably because it is already soft deleted and `first()` returns `null`

Comment: how can i know if it's soft deleted or not its delete_at = 4/25/2015 11:44:48 AM

Comment: Then it is soft delete. Set the value manually to `null` to "undelete"

Comment: Thanks, fixed please add ur solution below to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your models have soft delete enabled, records where `deleted_at` is not `null` won't be returned when you make a query. Therefore you try to call `delete()` on `null` and this causes the error.

Set the deleted_at manually to `null` to "undelete" the record during testing.

Furthermore you probably should check if the model is `null` before deleting:

```
$province = Province::with('country')->where('id', $id)->first();

if($province != null){
    $province->delete();
}
```

Comment: without ``if``: ``Province::with('country')->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail()->delete();``

Comment: @limonte `Province::with('country')->findOrFail($id)->delete()` ;)

Comment: exactly what I thought! :)